# How to get length and values of array in php

Tags: php, laravel

I have this array

```
  Array
(
    [name] => ["John", "Robert"]
    [address] => ["California", "Scranton"]
    
)
```

I tried to get value of name, like first name is John, then second name is Robert, but when i try to accessed it like $request->name[0], i only get "J" character.
I tried to get its type, `echo gettype($request->name)`, it was return string.
And how to count its content that separated by comma?

Thank you

Comment: Could you rather var_export() and show your data?

Comment: Tried var_export, get this  
`array
(
    'name'=> '["John", "Robert"]'
    'address' => '["California", "Scranton"]'
    
)
`

Comment: `$request['name'][0]` will return John.

Comment: i got '[' character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have value as `'["John", "Robert"]'` which is stored as a JSON string. You can do a [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode it into an array and get the data.

```
<?php
 
 $request = array ('name'=> '["John", "Robert"]','address' => '["California", "Scranton"]');
 
 $request['name'] = json_decode($request['name'],true);
 
print_r($request['name'][0]);// or echo $request['name'][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_values to to get the values of array like this:

```
list($firstName, $lastName) = array_values($value)[0];
```

now $`firstName` is John, and $`lastName` is Robert